# How to delete multiple objects using s3 api?

Tags: amazon-s3

How to delete multiple objects using s3 api?

```
cat delete.json
{
    "Objects":
    [
    {
        "Key": "firstlevelfolder1/secondlevelfolder1/one.pdf",
        "Key": "firstlevelfolder1/secondlevelfolder1/two.pdf"
    }
    ],
    "Quiet": false
}
```

And try to delete using s3 api like below but it deleted only two.pdf file, any suggestion please.

```
aws s3api delete-objects --bucket $bucketNameToUse --delete file://delete.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input json is invalid. Try below input. Objects has to be Array of Key sub documents.

```
{
    "Objects": [
        {
            "Key": "firstlevelfolder1/secondlevelfolder1/one.pdf"
        },
        {
            "Key": "firstlevelfolder1/secondlevelfolder1/two.pdf"
        }
    ],
    "Quiet": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but still I'm wondering if json itself is wrong then how come s3 api "delete command" worked and deleted file two.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can delete s3 elements in distribuited mode with this step function :[AWS Examples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-stepfunctions-examples/tree/main/sam/demo-bulk-delete-s3-objects)